# Sliding Pane Layout Focus Issue?

Tags: android

I am using this GitHub Project to create a sliding panel from top :-

https://github.com/6wunderkinder/android-sliding-layer-lib/

and here is my xml :-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.dev_task_login_ui.SlidingLayer xmlns:SlidingLayer="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.dev_task_login_ui"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/slidingLayer1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    SlidingLayer:stickTo="top" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/sliding_pane_padding_right"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/sliding_pane_padding_left"
        android:layout_gravity="center|top"
        android:background="@drawable/sliding_pane_corner" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/swipeText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/sliding_pane_text_padding_bottom"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/sliding_pane_text_padding_top"
            android:textColor="#074035"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</com.example.dev_task_login_ui.SlidingLayer>
```

I am inflating this in the mail xml using `addView` method in MainActivity.

Now the issue is when this sliding pane is visible , obviously it forms on the top of the main layout, So if i want to click a button in the main layout

I have to touch the screen two times, first to remove the focus from the sliding pane - hiding it and second to actually click the button.

**So is it possible that the focus remains on the main layout even if the sliding pane forms on top of it ?**